Centre turning point of the reflect tool - Illustrator CC
Is there a way to centre the turning point when flipping horizontally using the reflect tool? I could manually adjust it but I want to make sure its in the centre of what I am trying to flip.


If you select the object, and merely double-click the tool in the toolbar, it will use the center of the object as the origin.
(This is the same as choosing Object > Transform > Reflect.. from the menu.)
This is also true for the Rotate Tool, Scale Tool, etc.

You can also use The Transform Panel.
Choose a point on the 9-point Origin Box, then use the Transform Panel Menu to "Flip Horizontal/Vertical" - it will use the origin box setting.


And there's also Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform to utilize the 9-point Origin as well, with a live preview - which would need to be expanded to "bake in".

it doesn't seem to work for me if I double click on the reflect tool. Do you mean in the toolbar? The point is still off centre

@user24115 Yes double-click the tool in the toolbar.

Adding to Scott's excellent answer and addressing your more particular issue...
In the screenshot below taken from your question's image, notice the cyan colored crosshair with a circle. With the Reflect tool selected this crosshair will be the center of rotation or reflection. This can be set manually by Option/ Alt clicking on your desired rotation center.

Particularly for your case the issue is you have Point Type selected and the rotation center defaults to the left side of the type (or the anchor point of the point type). You can simply Option/ Alt click at your desired center of rotation to define where you want it. You can also use Area Type which would have it's center located at the center of the type both horizontally and vertically.
As an aside—the cyan color of the rotation center indicator can be changed in settings by changing the color used for Guides (Illustrator> Settings> Guides & Grid). I find the cyan color a bit hard to see on a white artboard.

These solutions are correct and helpful. I found the specific issue I was having was in relation to type. My text was set as point type which made the centre point default to the bottom left of the text box - I'm not sure why this is. When I double clicked the reflect tool in the tool bar as Scott suggested it didn't change. However once I converted to Area type it defaults to the centre. Also if I move the centre point and double click on the reflect tool this time it works and automatically recentres.
Point type

Area Type


Point or Area Type should not have mattered. The "dot" for point type merely indicated the text alignment but the object should reflect as I described regardless of the text alignment. I'm glad you got to here you wanted. But the point text wasn't the issue.

@Scott ohh ok so that was the issue then was the text alignment being left aligned. Yes have tried with the point type centre aligning it and it works now
